# AudioKit iOS Setting Input and Output devices

Tags: ios, swift, core-audio, audio-recording, audiokit

Have an app that can record audio and play it with another audio simultaneously.

What I Want: To be able to switch Audio Input And Output devices. For example. Record Audio from iPhone build in mic and listen audio through wired or bluetooth headphones. and vice versa

What am I trying to do:

```
            do {
                print("Seted Input:\(String(describing: AudioKit.inputDevice))")
                if let inputs = AudioKit.inputDevices {
                    print("Selected Input:\(String(describing: [indexPath.row]))")
                    try AudioKit.setInputDevice(inputs[indexPath.row])
                    try PlayerManager.sharedInstance.mic.setDevice(inputs[indexPath.row])
                    print("Selected Input:\(String(describing: AudioKit.inputDevice))")
                }
            } catch let error as NSError{
                print(error)
            }
```

Result:

```
Seted Input:Optional(<Device: Микрофон гарнитуры (Wired Microphone)>)
Selected Input:<Device: iPhone Микрофон (Built-In Microphone Снизу)>
Selscted Input:Optional(<Device: Микрофон гарнитуры (Wired Microphone)>)
Selected Output:Optional(<Device: Наушники (Wired Headphones)>)
```

Question: How to properly set input device with AudioKit.

I'am using xCode 9.3 (9E145) and AudioKit (4.2.1)

P.S It would be great if some one help me with output setting too.
AudioKit.outputDevices always return 1 device to me, even if bluetooth and wired headphones connected

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the same problem

Comment: No. still no luck

Comment: Did you find out the solution in the end?

Answer (score 0):

```
do {
        try AudioKit.setInputDevice(AudioKit.inputDevices![0])
    } catch {
        AKLog("AudioKit setInputDevice failed")
    }
```